# type casting in python error handling

Tags: python, file-io

SO I am reading a text file which has 2 columnn

```
 foo, bar
```

SO i did something like

```
for each_line in f:
   each_line = each_line.split(',')
   foo = int(each_line[0])
   bar = int(each_line[1]
   foobar = FooBar(foo,bar)
   foobar_list.append(foobar)
```

Now, sometimes either foo or bar is blank.. hence cant be typecasted to int..
Is there a way that if something where foo or bar is empty I can just skip this feature

(doesnt get appended to foodbar) but then the loops stills keeps on going ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple of places this could possibly fail, either if each_line doesn't have enough commas, or if either value was not a number (say, an empty string).  In each case, you can catch the error and use `continue` to skip to the next item in `f`:

```
for each_line in f:
   try:
       foo_line, bar_line = each_line.split(',')
   except ValueError:
       # "Too many/few values to unpack" meaning wrong number of commas!
       continue
   try:
       foo, bar = int(foo_line), int(bar_line)
   except ValueError:
       # "invalid literal for int()" meaning it wasn't digits
       continue
   foobar = FooBar(foo,bar)
   foobar_list.append(foobar)
```

I've broken this down into two, separate exception handlers because there are two different ways for it to fail.  You actually could fold it up like:

```
for each_line in f:
   try:
       foo_line, bar_line = each_line.split(',')
       foo, bar = int(foo_line), int(bar_line)
   except ValueError:
       # there was invalid input.
       continue
   foobar = FooBar(foo,bar)
   foobar_list.append(foobar)
```

Since it's the same exception and they happen close together.  Personally, i prefer the former to make it really clear that there are two kinds of errors.  What you should NOT do is:

```
# !!! BAD !!!
for each_line in f:
    try:
        each_line = each_line.split(',')
        foo = int(each_line[0])
        bar = int(each_line[1]
        foobar = FooBar(foo,bar)
        foobar_list.append(foobar)
    except ValueError:
        continue
```

because `FooBar()` or even `foobar_list.append()` could fail, but the exception handler can swallow it; Always make the `try:` suite in yoru exception handlers as small as possible so that they only catch one error, and where the error is is easy to find.

Answer (score 1):

This is an exceptional example of Exception Handling

```
for each_line in f:
   each_line = each_line.split(',')
   try:
       foo = int(each_line[0])
       bar = int(each_line[1]
       foobar = FooBar(foo,bar)
       foobar_list.append(foobar)
   except ValueError:
       None
```

Answer (score 0):

This tests if they're empty (assuming they're strings):

```
if not foo or not bar:
    continue
```

Comment: `int()` will still crash before you get there.

Comment: then check this first, *then* do the conversion

Answer (score 0):

Just in case a part has just spaces:

```
if foo.strip() != "":
    foo = int(each_line[0])
else:
    ???
```

Comment: That condition can be shortened to `if foo.strip():`.